# Tool for check valid test cases in Salesforce?

Tags: unit-test, tools

We have a existing project which has a number of invalid test cases - which means, test cases only have the code coverage but don't have system.assert in it. I remember there is a tool to find those test methods but I can't find it now. Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Checkmarx Security Scanner](http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner) will provide this insight as well as many more risks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I haven't found any alternative way of doing this. However, I am a little bit reluctant to do this because: 1, checking the validity of test cases is a simply task which shouldn't require static analyzer (And a static analyzer usually provides too much information) 2, this task should be able to be handled locally without the using of cloud.